# clang-format: indentation of preprocessor continuation line

Tags: c++, clang-format

Clang-format v14 formats the following line like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(signal_rates, reference_rates) private(  \
  exposure_times, weights, jacobian)
```

But Clang-format v16 formats it like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(signal_rates, reference_rates) private(  \
    exposure_times, weights, jacobian)
```

Is there a way to make the two versions agree with each other? Both use the same `.clang-format` which contains `ContinuationIndentWidth: 2`.

I ask because my code is tested in a container which uses clang-format 14 but my personal computer has Arch Linux with clang-format 16. I could manually install clang-format 14 on my computer to resolve the discrepancy but I wonder if there is a way to avoid that. Otherwise both versions produce exactly the same output.

Comment: Could this be tab vs space difference?

Comment: There are no tabs anywhere in the code.